# How to use material design?

Tags: java, android, gradle, material-design

Hi currently following a tutorial for creating floating labels on an application. Attempting to use the design dependencies before realising AndroidX requires the use of 'com.google.android.material:material-rc1' Im just confused as to how to use it and how to resolve the dependency.

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material-rc11.1.0'
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: open the build.gradle file for your app and add the above code within the dependencies block

Comment: May be `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` ?

Comment: Attempted this and it resulted in could not resolve dependency